# Select the right row of record

Tags: php, mysqli

I cannot find the problem. Can you help me what is wrong with variable `$rows['book_id']`. It doesn't echo anything. Do I have make some `$_SESSION` variable or what shall I do. I have tried to find a solution without success.

```
    <?php
    $query=$conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT book_name, writer, book_id, countpc FROM `book` b
    JOIN `read` r
    ON (b.book_id = r.book)
    JOIN count_public_comment p ON
    (p.book=r.book)
    WHERE(b.book_id>'95')") or die ($conn->error);

    echo "<table id='table1'
    <br>
    <tr>
    <th>Bookname</th>
    <th>Writer</th>
    <th>Count of comments</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<form action=test2.php method=post>";       
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['book_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['writer'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['countpc'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $rows['book_id'] . "> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=comment value=comments" . " </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }

if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
$sql=$conn->query("SELECT public_comment, stars FROM `read` WHERE `read`.book = '{$rows['book_id']}'" ) or die ($conn->error);
}
echo "<table id='table1'>
<br>
<tr>
<th>Public_comments</th>
<th>stars</th>
</tr>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['public_comment'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['stars'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: `$row` instead of `$rows`?

Comment: Thanks. But It didn help.

Comment: I was looking at the same. when lost with your resulting array try echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);echo "</pre>" it'll show you what you need to know

Comment: The above will also tell you when the array is in a sub array i.e. $row[0]['book_id']

Comment: you are checking the value to see right, what you have wont print anything in a box, but will print in the value area. 

Also use $row, not $rows

Comment: You're viewing the source and not seeing it right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this part

```
if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
   $sql=$conn->query("SELECT public_comment, stars FROM `read` WHERE `read`.book = '{$rows['book_id']}'" ) or die ($conn->error);
}
```

Then the problem is that `$rows['book_id']` does not exist. It should be `$row['book_id']`. You also need to move everything pertaining to the comments into the `while` loop, since they are dependent on the `book_id`. Like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<form action=test2.php method=post>";       
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['book_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['writer'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['countpc'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['book_id'] . "> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=comment value=comments" . " </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
        $sql=$conn->query("SELECT public_comment, stars FROM `read` WHERE `read`.book = {$row['book_id']}" ) or die ($conn->error);
    }
    echo "<table id='table1'>
    <br>
    <tr>
    <th>Public_comments</th>
    <th>stars</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['public_comment'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['stars'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tryed to put right above while loop. No success. And $rows is $row.

Comment: Ok. But there is no table like read.book_id. I have read.book table. Thanks imtherman. I change code like you have. No result.

Comment: Is `$row['book_id']` being printed out in the hidden `input` field above it?

Comment: Well, if it's not then that means the `book_id` is blank, which would be the problem.

Comment: Ok. I will check that.. Just a moment. No. Still no result.

Answer (score 0):

is this the line that doesn't echo?

```
 echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $rows['book_id'] . "> </td>";
```

If so this should work

```
 echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=\"" . $rows['book_id'] . "\"> </td>";
```

Comment: No. This is the problem."SELECT public_comment, stars FROM `read` WHERE `read`.book = '{$row['book_id']}'". That variable $row['book_id'] doesent work. I have check that if I replace $row['book_id']  forexample to '51'(=id of known book) it works.

Comment: you are not making sense, post the result of the output

Comment: Keaner. How to do that.."post the result of the output"? Sorry I am learning this to use this forum

Comment: load the page, view the source of the page and copy and paste.

Comment: I tryed. I am using localhost and it seems that I cannot view the source. But I will try another browser..

Comment: Firefox gives the source code but there is too many characters to Comment